# ListView and layout. Why ListView overlaps everything?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

**This is edited version!** I'm new to programming Android apps and I think that this is really difficult, not the java but ui. I am trying to get a list of categories. They can be checkboxes with textview inside the listView or something else. Idea is that an user can just press the boxes/tags/checkboxes/buttons, multiselect. I ended up with checkboxes, because it felt the easiest way, any suggestions how to get easiest solution for end users? User can add categories of his own, so the last row is like button where user can add new categories.

**PROBLEM**

How can I get a layout where those category checkboxes not overlap settings bar, buttons etc.
**Partly solved:** I changed the framelayout to LinearLayout and I changed my splash image from imageView to android:background to layout. Now I can see everything but the order is not right. If I move  topframe to top (where it should be), I got the error message like this:

**ERROR:** 
   java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

**ACTIVITY.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/category"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_button"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:text="@string/category"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tak"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_button"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:text="@string/take"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/white_button"
        android:minHeight="40dp"
        android:text="@string/list"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/topframe"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#99a8b3b9" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/settings_button"
        android:layout_width="43dp"
        android:layout_height="37dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_sysbar_quicksettings" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/top_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:text="@string/no_category_text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: What is your parent ViewGroup in your layout?

Comment: I was just coming to this, I THINK that this is the problem. <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a FrameLayout to build an UI like this. A FrameLayout puts all childs in the top left corner, that's why your views are overlapping. What I have seen a LinearLayout with vertical orientation should do the job.

Use one like this for example:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:orientation="vertical">

    ...

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topframe"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#99a8b3b9" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/settings_button"
            android:layout_width="43dp"
            android:layout_height="37dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_sysbar_quicksettings" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/top_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:text="@string/no_category_text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="377dp" >
    </ListView>

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'll try this too. I think that there might be problem with those buttons which overlaps the background image, I just guess so...

Comment: I tried this and now I can see just a splash screen with image, no checkboxes, no buttons, nothing but splash image.   <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />

Comment: EDIT: I took off imageview and used instead android:background="@drawable/splash" > in linearLayout. Now this is working but buttons are the top most, then topframe and then checkboxes. This is fun :)